# Split string by next line and group them by 3 in array

Tags: javascript, string, split

I have a sample input in a textarea like this (numbers are displayed in next line)

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

How can I do this in JavaScript so I can get result of an array like this :

```
array("123", "456")
```

The string should be grouped by 3 in an array. This assumes that the input are always divisible by 3

Comment: what have you tried so far? How are you dividing the text, in triplets, in half, or some other method?

Comment: If we'd answer the question you wrote in the title, the result would be `["1","2","3","4","5","6"]`. Please clarify what you want.

Comment: Ive updated the question.. should grouped by 3 based on what i have stated in my expected output

Answer (score 0):

- Get the value from the text.
- Pattern match the text on groups of 3 numbers (with anything in between).
- Remove all the junk in between

  ```
  $("#textAreaID").val()
    .match(/(\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)/g)
    .map(function(e){
      return e.replace(/\D+/g, '');
    });
  ```

Comment: Nice one-liner. What happens on line 10? Or when you have real, dynamic data on those lines?

Comment: The question states `This assumes that the input are always divisible by 3`. I'll let @bogz check his assumptions.

Comment: this does not work with two digit numbers. like 10 or 11 or 12

Comment: fixed it, assuming you only want integers